# Anyone successfully deploy a Spring 4 MVC + GAE application?

Tags: spring-mvc, google-app-engine

The Spring 4 MVC + GAE HelloWorld application run successfully in local, but failed after deploying to App Engine Standard. Got below error

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

spring-servlet.xml

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring4MVCHelloWorldDemo Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Below error log from GAE:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletRequestHandledEvent
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2591)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2943)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:350)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:203)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:176)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:133)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:635)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:595)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:565)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletRequestHandledEvent
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-85e29f0941d0ef63(Request.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2591)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2943)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:350)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
... 1 more
request_id: "58efb14800ff0694c84e7a3c260001737e6a6f6266666572310001323031373034313474303131303235000100" 
timestamp: "2017-04-13T17:11:37.491Z" 
enter code here
```

Comment: Yes. I have lots and lots of website deployed on GAE. http://www.tripsonclicks.com is one such example.

Comment: Add your applicationContext.xml, spring-servlet.xml and web.xml here.

Comment: I copy most of the code as a starting point from [link](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-full-example/). The code work successfully local, but not after deploy to GAE